# How can I make a method repeat itself? Java

Tags: java, loops, methods, iteration

I have a method that fills an array and I need to find a way to make it repeat a number of times. The purpose is to iterate and reiterate the density of a planet to narrow its mass,gravity and densities at specific points which are concentric shells. This is my first program but, I have learned a decent amount while working on this I think. Thanks everyone

Here is my code sample of the density calculation. I probably included too much but oh well. So I need to make this iterate selected number of times. Each iteration needs to be put back into the mass calculation which will then be put back into the gravity calculation. And then the show starts again.

```
public class ItrDensityGrid {

    public double itrrho[];
    double b = InitialConditions.bmod;  

    // Iterating grid of densities 

    public ItrDensityGrid(int shells, double radius, double mass){

            GravityGrid gg = new GravityGrid(shells, radius, mass); 

            for(int k = shells; k >= 0; k--){

                    itrrho[k] = (itrrho[k]*(1+(gg.alpha[k]*(1.0 / 2)))*(1 / (1-((gg.alpha[k])*(1.0 / 2)))));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: either call the method in any conditional block or make the method call itself on a condition .

Comment: It'd be best if you could provide a code sample of what it does currently.

Comment: It will be great if you could provide some sample code as well. That way people can answer more accurately. From mere description, they can only guess a solution.

Comment: Try to google how to do recursion, you probably need to call the method recursively.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the help of [**Recursion**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion), or looping.

In recursion, you call the method again from inside of the method itself. Make sure to call (or return) conditionally, otherwise, it may lead to infinite loop!

Here is an example **with recursion**:

```
public planetMars (double density, double mass) {

    // do your calculations 
    density = density / 10.05312;
    mass = mass / 7.2378;
    myArray[] = density; // or whatever you want        

    // if calculations have not narrowed enough, call recursively
    if ( density > 5.2)
        planetMars (density, mass);
}
```

alternatively, **with loop**, you may do something like:

```
public planetMars (double density, double mass) {

    // loop unless the calculation is not cool
    while ( density > 5.2) {
        // do your calculations 
        density = density / 10.05312;
        mass = mass / 7.2378;
        myArray[] = density; // or whatever you want    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make a function which checks if the tolerances of your calculations are already good enough, here is some "pseudocode"

```
 while(toleranceIsGood(planet) == false)
 {
      planet = calculatePlanet(planet);
 }
```

planet would be the array. of course you can implement things like Endless loop detection etc